# Looking for a word, phrase or expression that means "not appreciating the present because of worrying about the future"?

Tags: single-word-requests

It's all in the title really. I'm looking for a word, phrase or expression that means "not appreciating the present because of worrying about the future"?

For example, when you have made an accomplishment, but cannot appreciate or recognize this success because you are preoccupied overthinking or overanalyzing future risks or outcomes.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Maybe it's some type of Cherophobia!

Comment: The term you used (*worry*) captures this sentiment.

Answer (score -1):

[Chronophobia](https://www.fearof.net/fear-of-the-future-phobia-chronophobia/) is used to express fear of the future.  However, I am not sure the definition explicitly includes the inability to enjoy the present.  Try "persistent chronophobia" to more specifically call out that out.

Comment: _Chronophobia is the fear of time. It’s characterized by an irrational yet persistent fear of time and of the passing of time_ so it doesn't really represent "not appreciating the present because of worrying about the future".

Comment: Anxiety = a feeling of worry, nervousness, or unease about something with an uncertain outcome (Google)